# Auto validation of methods with hibernate validator 5.x + EJB

Tags: cdi, ejb-3.1, hibernate-validator

I have following environment:

- Glassfish 4
- hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar (in ear)

Now I try to implement auto validation of method parameters:

```
@Local
@ValidateOnExecution(type = ExecutableType.ALL)
public interface SomeServiceLocal {

   String someMethod(@Size(max = 1) String value);

}
```

in execution of:

```
@Stateless
public class OtherBean implements OtherBeanLocal {

  @Inject
  private SomeServiceLocal someService;

     @Override
     public String otherMethod() {
       return someService.someMethod("abc");
     }

  }

}
```

I supposed that invocation of someMethod will cause a validation error. Why it is not working?

Comment: Method validation should work automatically as soon as you use Bean Validation annotations. You don't even have to add (and probably should not, unless you have a good reason) the Validator artifact to the ear. Bean Validation is provided by the container. That said, I am not sure why it is not happening in your case. Is there anything in the logs (have you enabled debug/trace logging)? Any exception?

Comment: I don't have any strange messages in log files.

Answer (score 0):

Remove hibernate validator from your EAR file.  when you embed it this way, auto registration won't work properly.  You'll need to use their CDI extension to register it instead.

Comment: I removed hibernate-validator from dependencies and result is the same. Maybe I need some additional configuration (interceptor, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by myself. It is necessary to add @ValidateOnExecution on the class level of bean implementation - SomeServiceBean